# How to configure two different APIs with the help of Cocoa pods?

Tags: ios9, cocoapods, afnetworking, sdwebimage, podfile

I have configured the AFNetworking API with the help of Cocoa Pods and now I have to configure SDWebImage. I tried to add "**platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'**"in my existing pod file but it is not working and giving me the following error as shown in the image.
[image]

Do I need to create separate pod file? If yes then where it should be located in my project directory.

This is my existing `Podfile`:

```
target ‘<MYAPPNAME>’ 
do 
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5' 
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8' 
end
```

Comment: Can you post your pod file? Also, what editor are you using to edit it?

Comment: target ‘<MYAPPNAME>’ do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
end
-----------------------------------------
This is after adding pod for SDWebImage

Comment: Did you try a `pod repo update`?

Comment: @Developer Are you using Obj-C or Swift? Looks like installation is slightly different for Swift. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation

Comment: I am using Objective C. And what is wrong with my pod file? And what "pod repo update" will do?

Comment: @Adrian Worked after running the command "pod repo update" :-)

Comment: @Developer `pod repo update` was a suggestion in the logs. My guess, but you could do a `man pod`, is that it update the local repository copy that it made to the wanted version (if for instance you got previous the version 2.1 of SDWebImage)  if needed.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your suggestion. Please write your comment in the answer so that I can Accept that. Moreover, where I can find these kind of more instructions as I wan to read them. Thanks!:-)